# Arpeggios and arranging songs like an epic film score

Tags: piano, composition, arranging

I saw [Tommee Profitt's Carol of the Bells](https://youtu.be/nj4Fz_Qe_O0) on YouTube and was wondering if there is some theory behind the creation of the runs used he used in this arrangement. I know that these are very much comprised of patterns and the blending of the patterns creates the feel in the music. My question is "How does (should) a pianist approach an arranging project to create such an epic, film-like sound?" (I understand that it is a mix of artistic ability and taste but also theory and chord progression).

Comment: take a look at technique's used in Philip Glass's music.. it has that same repetitive pattern that is used in alot of cinematic type film scenes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNiOqa1nWgI

Comment: @foreyez Philip Glass? Interesting proposal. I'll look into it. Thank you!

Comment: I felt like the "movie feel" was mostly induced by the drums and the loud bass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would study some of Hans Zimmer's piano scores, specifically Inception, and The Dark Knight.

Film music relies primarily on basic theory. Such as voice leading, simple chord progressions, arpeggios, modulation (a little more advanced), repetition, musical form, etc...

If you wanted to learn more about Film scoring... I would recommend [Rick Beato's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J8KrZjs6uk&list=PLW0NGgv1qnfwr_4EFLfdBMMHKZGanVeo_) tutorials on Film Scoring. Good Luck!

Comment: Rick Beato has some great stuff! I also really enjoy Nahre Sol's channel as it brings a very interesting classical perspective. Hans Zimmer's "Dunkirk" is an amazing piece as well... so dissonant and suspenseful (as is expected from a war time movie). His creation of that score is absolutely brilliant!